# C#: form in project not showing up in intellisense

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a form in a project.  The new form is listed in the solution explorer as being in this project.

But the form is not showing up in the intellisense listing when I try to create an object variable in order to show the form.

Is there something else that needs to happen after you add form to a project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check that your forms are in the same namespace?

Comment: This was the issue. The reason the namespace was incorrect is because I cut and paste the form from one project to another.

Comment: Not the best habit to get into ;)